# Nested JSON object and JSON array in android

Tags: android

Nested JSON object and JSON array in android

```
{
        "ocrNumber": "0123456",
        "userName": "dddd",
        "photo": [{
            "lat": "13.1234",
            "long": "7.1234",
            "imagepath": "sd / image / demo.jpg"
        }]
    }
```

please ignore the syntax if wrong

Comment: so what is your problem and what you want ?

Comment: What do you really want us to help you with?

Comment: What is going on here ? Please format your Question.

Comment: Actually i am not able to convert it into code..i am facing some problem here ...

Comment: i am a new user of android for that i need ur help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

post you json in [this](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) and you will get the models in zip.You can easily add them to your app

Answer (score -1):

```
    // Make The Json Arrya in Json Object Programeticall.
    //                    JSONObject person1 = new JSONObject();
    //                    try {
    //                        if(contacts_arraylist.get(j).getName()!=null) {
    //                            person1.put("name", contacts_arraylist.get(j).getName());
    //                        }
    //                        else {
    //                            person1.put("name","");
    //                        }
    //
    //                        if(contacts_arraylist.get(j).getEmails().size()>0)
    //                        {
    //                            person1.put("email", contacts_arraylist.get(j).getEmails().get(0).address);
    //                        }
    //                        else {
    //                            person1.put("email", "");
    //                        }
    //
    //                        if(contacts_arraylist.get(j).getNumbers().size()>0)
    //                        {
    //                            person1.put("mobile_number", contacts_arraylist.get(j).getNumbers().get(0).number);
    //                        }
    //                        else {
    //                            person1.put("mobile_number", "");
    //                        }
    //
    //                        personarray.put(person1);
    //                    } catch (JSONException e) {
    //                        e.printStackTrace();
    //                    }
  );
        }
    }

    private void signOut() {
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {
                        /*Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Loged Out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
       // Log.d("GOOGLE_LOGIN", "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);

    }
}
```